# Stop, and start thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is there a way to stop and start a thread? I want the user to be able to stop and start a function at will.
ex:

```
void func()
{
while (1)
{
cout << "I am a function!" << endl;
}
}

void stopfunc();
{
if (condition...)
t1.stop(); (???)
}
}

int main()
{
thread t1(func);
thread t2(stopfunc)

t1.join();
t2.join();
}
```

EDIT: I tried what someone in the comments suggested, this didn't work:

```
    atomic<bool> stop_func{ false };

    void toggle()
    {
        while (1)
        {
            Sleep(20);

            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F6))
            {
                stop_func = true;
            }
        }
    }

    int Func()
    {
        while (!stop_func)
        {
            HWND h = FindWindow(NULL, "....");

            if (!process->Attach("..."))
                return 1;

            Interface::OnSetup();
            Static::OnSetup();
            Dynamic::OnSetup();

            if (!g_pOverlay->Attach(h))
                return 2;

            g_pRenderer->OnSetup(g_pOverlay->GetDevice());

            hFont = g_pRenderer->CreateFont("Verdana", 12, FONT_CREATE_SPRITE | FONT_CREATE_OUTLINE | FONT_CREATE_BOLD);

            g_pOverlay->AddOnFrame(OnFrame);

            return g_pOverlay->OnFrame();
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
    thread t1(Func);
    thread t2(toggle);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A simple way to do it is to set a flag and have the other thread periodically check it. Make sure you are using atomic operations. Without cooperation of some sort from the thread being stopped, it's not possible in standard C++, and for good reasons.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by flag?

Comment: `std::atomic<bool> stop_func{false}; void func() { while(!stop_func) {...} } void stopfunc() { stop_func = true; }`

Comment: This was what I needed, thanks. Why not use a normal bool though? What's an atomic bool?

Comment: Nevermind, it didn't work. Posted my code in the OP

Comment: Well, your `Func`'s loop body will only execute at most once anyway (since it unconditionally returns at the end), so of course it doesn't work.

Comment: @T.C. Oh, so there's no way I can toggle that function's thread on and off?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a direct, portable way to start or stop a thread.

You can come fairly close by setting a flag, and having the thread yield when/if the flag is set:

```
class foo { 
    std::atomic<bool> flag;
public:
    void pause() { flag = true; }
    void unpause() { flag = false; }

    void operator() { 
       for (;;) {
            if (flag) yield(); 
            _do_other_stuff();
       }
    }
};
```

If you really need the thread to stop completely, you can use [`native_handle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle) to get a native handle to the thread. Then, since you're apparently writing for Windows, you can use you can use [`SuspendThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686345.aspx) and [`ResumeThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685086.aspx) to truly suspend and resume the thread--but of course, code the code that does that won't be portable.

Comment: It's not just portability issues. The thread being suspended could be holding a mutex, potentially leading to a deadlock, or in the middle of altering some data structure, leaving it in an inconsistent state, etc.

Comment: @T.C.: As long as the thread doing the suspending doesn't hold any mutex (or semaphore, etc.) when it suspends another thread, and the rest of the code uses synchronization properly, suspending a thread is fairly safe. Other threads depending on that one may well stall too, but it shouldn't lead to deadlock.

Comment: `void thread1() { new int; }  void thread2() { suspend(thread1); new int; resume(thread1); }` can definitely deadlock if thread1 is suspended while it's holding the heap's lock.

Comment: Okay--poor wording. The thread doing the suspending shouldn't hold (or attempt to get) a mutex anytime it has another thread suspended. And yes, obtaining the mutex can easily be indirect, so it's not necessarily immediately obvious.

Comment: So, based on this is there a way I can use this for my situation?

Comment: @michealbell: You'll really need to define what you want to accomplish a little more thoroughly before anybody can give a very meaningful answer. I've shown a couple of things you certainly *can* in the answer--but whether they'll accomplish what you really want is open to a lot more question (because I'm not really sure what you want).

Comment: In total, I simply want the user to be able to toggle (turn on and off) the "func" int I posted in the OP. I've been trying for a long time and it'd make me so happy to finally solve this :)

Comment: @michealbell: Let me rephrase: Yes, you can definitely stop the thread. The question is whether that's a good idea, or perhaps your entire application will crash and burn when you do it.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Well, I atleast want to try stopping and resuming it.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Could you provide an example using SuspendThread how I can use it for my situation?

Comment: @michealbell - Believe me, I know what I'm saying. You should not use `SuspendThread()` in any case where you have access to your thread source. It seems like an easy solution (You don't have to mess with volatile variables and such), but IRL it introduces countless threading issues like the ones mentioned by **T.C.** . If you ever use `SuspendThread()` in your code you will have to care for its variables, flags, sync objects, and  - what most people tend to forget - _to resume and gloriously finish your thread on program termination to prevent leaks_ . It **is** a nightmare.